# How could I know that my mail was successfully sent by Sendmail

Tags: sendmail

When I use sendmail command to send a email and then execute `echo $?` it returns "0", but I didn't receive the mail and the log shows:

> stat=Deferred: Connection reset by mxbiz2.qq.com

How could I know that my mail was successfully sent?

Comment: please provide code which are sending email.

Comment: cat testmsg |sendmail  -O LogLevel=16 -v  -t sss@58.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in the email you are sending set a bounce address that is attached to a mailbox you can process with a script (with procmail for example)

Next, during the actual sending make a note of the id of the email and the address it is sending too.  Store this in a database.  Then periodically scan the logs for the id numbers.  If there are any messages such as the "deferred" message you mention or other problems, then log the activity in the database

Finally, if any messages bounce then compare them with the database and mark those addresses as bad

After a while your database can be used to generate reporting and status for the email addresses

This isn't a 100% approach for such a lot of complicated checking but standard SMTP email doesn't do guaranteed delivery or receipts, it isn't like that